# What goes in app/Resources and what goes in Acme/MainBundle/Resources

Tags: symfony

I am starting a new project using Symfony2. I am adding some basic twig templates like my CSS template (with assetic to trigger sass -- nifty) and my header/footer template. My question is, should this sort of thing go into app/Resources or into Acme/MainBundle/Resources?

I am sure I can do either if I really wanted to, but I'd like to know what the correct way to do it is.

```
app
    Resources
        <A. here?>
src
    Acme
        MainBundle
            Resources
                <or B. here?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really a matter of preference. I tend to keep global views in app/Resources. Does your MainBundle contain anything else besides views? If not, I think that's more reason to use app/Resources and avoid unnecessary bundle pollution.

Comment: I agree that makes sense, but then on the other hand I have these sass files. Should they too go in app/Resources/assets/css/ ?

Comment: I think it makes sense to keep them grouped together with your other global assets, whether you keep them in apps/Resources or in MainBundle.

Comment: Thanks for your help. To future question-readers: I decided to put them in my MainBundle, along with my other global assets like images.